# tabindex is not behaving correctly with polymer-3 iron-scroll-threshold in firefox

Tags: firefox, polymer-3.x

tabindex is not working as expected in firefox only when used inside iron-scroll-threshold and iron-list. It is selecting complete container on pressing tab and then not moving to list-items. It's working fine in chrome.

I have tried providing tabindex="-1" to iron-scroll-threshold and iron-list but then it is not even moving to container.

```
<iron-scroll-threshold on-lower-threshold="loadMoreUserListData" lower-threshold="100" id="threshold" scroll-target="usersListing">
    <div id="usersListing" class="listContainerHeight">
        <iron-list id="listing_iron_list" items="{{List}}" restamp=true as="item">
            <template>
                <div class="mainContainer" tabindex$="[[tabIndex]]">{{item.name}}</div>
            </template>
        </iron-list>
    </div>
</iron-scroll-threshold>
```

expected behavior is that on pressing tabs it should read list-items and not just the whole container with list list list.

Comment: is it happening in other browser too? Never the less this seems like a bug and you should report it to the owner of the repo!

Comment: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-scroll-threshold

Comment: @PascalL. not happening in Chrome, it's working just as expected. I'll check and report as you mentioned. Thanks